# Finding multiple documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, mongoose

I wrote a Mongoose Node/Express application. I have 4 documents. I am trying to write a [route (end point)](http://localhost:3000/api/auth/seats/:tableid) to get all seats for a table with their full data. I get a response like I expect.

I want to know if there is a better way to write the application like this.

seat.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const SeatScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    table: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Table',
        required: true
    },
    event: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Event',
        require: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Seat', SeatScheme);
```

course.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CourseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    seat: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Seat'
    },
    meal: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Meal'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);
```

meal.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const MealSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    img: String,
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Meal', MealSchema);
```

category.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    displayname: String,
    type: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Categoty', CategorySchema);
```

seat.route.js

```
const Seat = require('../../models/seat/seat.model');
const Course = require('../../models/course/course.model');
const Meal = require('../../models/meal/meal.model');
const Category = require('../../models/category/category.model');

module.exports = function (Router) {
    Router.get('/seats/:tableid', (req, res) => {

        Seat.find({ table: req.params.tableid }, (err, seats) => {
            const seatsPromise = seats.map(seat => {
                return Course.find({ seat: seat._id }).then((courses) => {
                    return Promise.all(courses.map(course => {
                        return Meal.findOne({ _id: course.meal }).then(meal => {
                            return Category.findOne({ _id: meal.category}).then(category => {
                                return {
                                    displayname: category.displayname,
                                    type: category.type,
                                    meal: meal
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    })).then( courses => {
                        return {
                            seat: seat._id,
                            courses: courses
                        };
                    });
                })
            });

            Promise.all(seatsPromise).then(seats => {
                res.json(seats);
            })
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't using mongoose `.populate()` method instead?

Refer to the Mongoose documentation for Population [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)